# Type safe usage of generic sealed classes

Tags: generics, kotlin, covariance, undocumented-behavior, sealed-class

I found interesting thing when I write generic sealed class. Here is first version:

```
// sample interface and implementation
interface MyInterface
class MyInterfaceImpl : MyInterface

sealed class Response<T: MyInterface>               

data class Success<T: MyInterface>(val payload: T) : Response<T>()
data class Failure(val errorCode: Int) : Response<MyInterface>()
object Cancelled : Response<MyInterface>()
```

let's say we also have *request function* like this:

```
fun <T: MyInterface> requestObject(cls : KClass<T>): Response<T> = TODO("Request")
```

now at the use side we have errors:

```
fun test() = when (val response = requestObject(MyInterfaceImpl::class)) {
    is Success -> print("Payload is ${response.payload}")     // Smart cast perfectly works!
    is Failure -> print("Error code ${response.errorCode}")   // Incomparable types: Failure and Response<MyInterfaceImpl>
    Cancelled -> print("Request cancelled")                   // Incomparable types: Cancelled and Response<MyInterfaceImpl>
}
```

> **First question**: `Failure` and `Cancelled` isn't use `T` for *in/out positions*, why this cast is unchecked and I need to suppress it?

After a while, [Konstantin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8490194/constorvar) show me solution how to declare *type safe sealed class*:

```
sealed class Response<out T: MyInterface>                    // <-- out modifier here

data class Success<T: MyInterface>(val payload: T) : Response<T>()
data class Failure(val errorCode: Int) : Response<Nothing>() // <-- Nothing as type argument
object Cancelled : Response<Nothing>()                       // <-- Nothing as type argument
```

This declaration works like a charm and now I have questions:

> **Second question**: why it's necessary to write `out` modifier here?
>
> **Third question**: why `Producer<Nothing>` is subtype of `Producer<MyInterface>`? By definition of covariant: `Producer<A>` is subtype of `Producer<B>` if `A` subtype of `B`, but `Nothing` isn't subtype of `MyInterface`. It looks like *undocumented extralinguistic feature*.

Comment: “but Nothing isn't subtype of MyInterface” — yes it is; `Nothing` is a subtype of every type.  (That's possible because it has no values.)

Answer (score 2):

The variance doesn't work out in the end. `Response<MyInterfaceImpl>` is not `Response<MyInterface>` and therefore `Failure` and `Cancelled` cannot be used. Eventhough you're not using the gerneric type, you still declare it.

When putting `out T`, you'll have an effect like `? extends T` in *Java*.

Then for [`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html#nothing) you have:

> Nothing has no instances. You can use Nothing to represent "a value that never exists".

This also means it's a subtype of everything and thus also works for the generics.

Comment: Thank you for response, but I can't completely agree with you because of I've tried to extend `Response` in Java and I have `? extends T` with and without "out projection"

Comment: "This also means it's a subtype of everything and thus also works for the generics" you post it as a quote, but I think it's only your guess. I can't found definition like this neither in documentation nor in "Kotlin in action" book

Comment: It's a conclusion. If there's no instance it'll always be possible to have it with out variance. That's how `TODO()` works as well. The quote part was a formatting issue. On the other hand _Kotlin_ is comparable to _Java_, not like it. I can't make a guess about the interactions between both.